# File that ensures that its content is complete when read

Tags: linux

I need to create files that contain data supplied by a running process (*A*). It will be read by one or more other processes (*B* and *C*). The first idea was to simply create a file and write the data to it. But now I am afraid that while process *A* writes the files and processes *B* and *C* or many others will read it, it might have only partial content.

I wonder if there is a way for my process *A* to create a file that acts like the files in `/sys` that are created by the kernel.

I also have thought about creating a named pipe. But I don't want any updates written to the file to be queued.

Another idea was to create some kind of semaphore files, but as there are an unknown number of other processes I am afraid that they will create a deadlock if one reading process dies or the update of the file will be slowed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be to use a temporary file, and then move it to replace the old one once the write is complete. So, in shell-like pseudocode:

```
$ write_new_file_state tmp_file
$ mv tmp_file file
```

What this ensures is that the file `file` is only updated atomically - either it contains the old contents, or it has been overwritten, and contains the new contents. Readers of the file will either see the old contents or the new, but not something incomplete, or some commbination of the two.

Note that, if you do this, you'll need to have the consumers close their file descriptors (`f.Close()` in Go) and explicitly re-open. The reason for this is that if they don't, they will still be holding a reference to the now-deleted old version of the file (file descriptors refer to file objects, not names, so overwriting the file doesn't change what existing file descriptors refer to).

Comment: Thanks! Is this behavior equal on all filesystems?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a property guaranteed by the Linux kernel. Quoting from `man 2 rename`: "If `newpath` already exists, it will be atomically replaced (subject to a few conditions; see ERRORS below), so that there is no point at which another process attempting to access `newpath` will find it missing." Also, "[i]f `newpath` exists but the operation fails for some reason, `rename()` guarantees to leave an instance of `newpath` in place."

Answer (score 1):

A common trick is to use `rename` system call to atomically put the file in place. This means you would have to write the file to a temporary filename and then rename.